# How do I copy this using Unix/Linux command line?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a folder structure like this:

```
MAT11NA_09_XX_XX_XXX
MAT11NA_09_XX_XX_XXXL
MAT11NA_11_XX_XX_XXX
MAT11NA_11_XX_XX_XXXL
MAT11NA_10_XX_XX_XXX
MAT11NA_10_XX_XX_XXXL
```

I want to copy from this server to another just the folder `MAT11NA_09_XX_XX_XXX`, but not `MAT11NA_09_XX_XX_XXX`**L**. When I finish with this I want to copy `MAT11NA_09_XX_XX_XXX`**L** but not `MAT11NA_09_XX_XX_XXX`.
This part **`MAT11NA_09_`** doesn't change, the **L** at the end also doesn't change.

The same for the rest of the folders...

How do I do this in Unix/Linux command line?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble reading this - in particular, I don't see any slashes in your description of your directory structure.  Any change you could simplify it a bit?

Comment: Are you asking how to copy something from one server to another? Or how to copy a folder? Or how to cope with long filenames?

Comment: WTF is that "belon" tag?!?

Answer (score 5):

With an "L"

```
cp -r *L destination
```

Without an "L"

```
cp -r *[^L] desyination
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's stupid, but at least it's straight forward.

This will copy all files/directories ending with L:

```
cp `ls | grep -E 'L$'` DEST
```

This will copy all files/directories **NOT** ending with L:

```
cp `ls | grep -vE 'L$'` DEST
```

Replace DEST with your destination.

Comment: Wouldn't "cp *L DEST" have been a lot simpler?

Comment: ls is not supposed to be used to generate filenames for shell expansion, it is intended for user presentation of filenames. You should really, really use just shell expansion, or find -print0/xargs -0.

Answer (score 1):

For the ones that you do want the L, just do:

```
scp -r MAT*L destserver:/whatever/
```

To do ones that do *not* have L, you want extended Globs with bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
scp -r ./!(MAT*L) destever:/whatever/
```

I haven't test this with scp, but this roughly a way to do it.  You could also consider using the find command with something like (for ones not with L).

```
find . ! -iname 'MAT*L' ! -iname '.*' -print0 | xargs -0 tar zcf foo.tar.gz
```

and then just copy the tar file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've tried all of them.

"`scp -r MAT*L destserver:/whatever/`" - this one looks like it's working.

```
shopt extglob
scp -r ./!(MAT*L) destever:/whatever/
```

For this one I ran the command "`shopt extglob`", then did the copy. But I got this error "`-bash: !: event not found`"...so, it's not working.

I tried also the first answer...
The folder structure is kinda like this:

```
folder1
   MAT11NA_09_XX_XX_XXX
   MAT11NA_09_XX_XX_XXXL
   MAT11NA_11_XX_XX_XXX
   MAT11NA_11_XX_XX_XXXL
   MAT11NA_10_XX_XX_XXX
   MAT11NA_10_XX_XX_XXXL
```

I want to take `MAT11NA_09_XX_XX_XXX` folders and put in a folder on another server.

Then I want to take `MAT11NA_09_XX_XX_XXXL` folder and put in another folder on another server.

Then...I want to take `MAT11NA_11_XX_XX_XXX` folders and put in in a folder (different from the folder where I put `MAT11NA_09_XX_XX_XXX`) on another server.

The same for `MAT11NA_11_XX_XX_XXXL`...

I don't want to put ALL L folders in one folder from another server, and I don't want to put ALL non-L folders in another one folder from another server.

Hope you understand this time, sorry. Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Ok, after the last answerr I am using these and it seems they are working:

```
scp -r MAT11NA_09_*L contentuser@/destination

scp -r MAT11NA_09_*[^L] contentuser@/destination
```

Comment: What about the find command option?

Comment: Or Denis' glob: ./*[^L]

Comment: You can link your Stack Overflow and Server Fault accounts: http://serverfault.com/users/21848?tab=accounts#sort-top

Comment: The "event not found" error is caused by the exclamation point "!" - you can avoid this error by running `set +H`